# Ng2-Admin-using exists components

Tags: angularjs, angular2-components, ng2-admin

I am new to angular 2/4,and I am trying to use ng2-admin as a base, and trying to build on to of it a full dash board includes beck-end. 
I am facing lots of issues while trying to use exist component(such as basic table) in a new simple module. I can't find any detailed documentation on ng2-admin beside creating new page. 
Is there anyone who can guide me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i found the solution

what actually i did was to redefine the Declarations/Providers correctly.

when using "ng" to generate new things,it is also adding unnecessary deceleration  in some places so this was my first mistake,also some used providers/services was needed to be declared on the right module.after understanding how the structure should be ,i kept the rules and i was able to add what i needed without any issues.

Comment: Can you share the solution?

Comment: Well,i do not have the exact example of the issue i raised in the thread,but the general idea is that you need to pay attention where you are the modules and the component are being registered. my issue was that it was not set in the top module and i had to remove it from the sub-module and move it to the base module (and remove any reference).